# Angularjs retrieving specific name / object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am not sure how to phrase the question, so please forgive me if it's wrong.
What I am trying to do is to retrieve the name from the array, for example :

[image]

The array look like this, and i want to retrieve just the "NAME" alone. Is that possible? PS: I want to retrieve from all ( eg. i got 50 counts, i want to retrieve all 50 names )

To add on, i have it stored like this : 
Thanks for any help in advance !

```
            $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                url: 'url'
                    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                        $scope.exhibitions = response.data.SrchResults;

                    }, function errorCallback(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    });
```

Comment: If you want only one then you can use $scope.exhibitions[0].ICON_NAME

Comment: From all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.exhibitions.length; i++){
    if (i > 0){
        alert($scope.exhibitions[i].NAME);
    }
}
```

Try putting this code at the line after

> $scope.exhibitions = response.data.SrchResults;

In order to display them. Try this

```
<div ng-repeat="exhibition in exhibitions">
    <span ng-if="exhibition.NAME">{{ exhibition.NAME }}</span>
</div>
```

The code is untested though. Feel free to adjust where it needs.

Comment: May i ask how do you store it so i can display ?

Comment: What do you mean by "store it"?

Comment: Uhh, cause this is alerting which is showing a pop up box, i am trying to display it like in a table. So do i like create an empty array to store it ?

Comment: You can use your variable "$scope.exhibitions" in the view.
To display them, you can use ng-repeat. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: I am trying to display just the name, not all the information in it

Comment: You use ng-repeat to iterate all of the objects inside the $scope.exhibitions then you can choose to display only the NAME of each object.

Comment: I edited to add how to display the data using ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of ES6 here.

JS

```
var srchResults = response.data.SrchResults;
var [first, ...exhibitions] = srchResults;
$scope.exhibitionNames = exhibitions.map(item=>item.NAME);
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="exhibitionName in exhibitionNames">
    <span ng-if="exhibitionName">{{exhibitionName}}</span>
</div>
```

Hope it will help somebody else. :)